# Сохранение токена для тестов

Tags: java, rest-assured

Есть класс, в котором я получаю токен:

```
class GetTokenTest
{
    String getTokenTest ()
    {
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given ().relaxedHTTPSValidation ();
        Response response = request.get (config.getToken);
        JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath ();
        String token = jsonPath.get ("access_token");
        return token;
    }
```

}

И пример класса, где я использую полученный токен:

```
class GetRulesTest
{
    GetTokenTest token = new GetTokenTest ();

    void getRulesTest ()
    {
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given ().relaxedHTTPSValidation().auth ().oauth2 (token.getTokenTest ());
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы сохранить токен для всех классов и использовать его без создания копии класса GetTokenTest?
Может, создать отдельный класс с фабричными методами? Или есть более простой способ?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен путем задания переменной в конфиге и объявления ее статической.